# Give $a,b,c>0.$ Prove that $\sum \sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}}\geq 3$

Tags: inequality, substitution

I proved this inequality in this way
$$\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}\geq\frac{b+c}{2}\left(\frac{1}{c+a}+ \frac{1}{a+b}\right)\geq\frac{b+c}{\sqrt{(c+a)(a+b)}},\cdots$$
$$ \left(\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}\right)\left( \frac{c}{a+b}+\frac{a}{b+c}\right)\left( \frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}\right)\ge1$$
$$\sum \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{a}{b+c}+\dfrac{b}{c+a}}\geq 3 \sqrt[9]{ \left(\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}\right)\left( \frac{c}{a+b}+\frac{a}{b+c}\right)\left( \frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}\right)}\geq 3$$

But i found this inequality proved in his way [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2130139p15574011)

Note

$$ \left( {\frac {b}{c+a}}+{\frac {c}{a+b}} \right)  \left( b \left( a+b
 \right) +c \left( c+a \right)  \right) ^{3} \left( c+a \right) 
 \left( a+b \right) = \left( ab+{b}^{2}+{c}^{2}+ac \right) ^{4}
$$
By Holder,we have

$$\left( {\it \sum} \left( \sqrt [3]{{\frac {b}{c+a}}+{\frac {c}{a+b}}}
 \right)  \right) ^{3}{\it \sum} \left(  \left( ab+{b}^{2}+{c}^{2}+ac
 \right) ^{3} \left( c+a \right)  \left( a+b \right)  \right) \geq 
 \left( {\it \sum} \left( ab+{b}^{2}+{c}^{2}+ac \right)  \right) ^{4}$$

Need to prove

$${\frac { \left( {\it \sum} \left( ab+{b}^{2}+{c}^{2}+ac \right) 
 \right) ^{4}}{{\it \sum} \left(  \left( ab+{b}^{2}+{c}^{2}+ac
 \right) ^{3} \left( c+a \right)  \left( a+b \right)  \right) }}\geq 27$$
<=>

$ \left( {\it \sum} \left( ab+{b}^{2}+{c}^{2}+ac \right)  \right) ^{4}\geq 
27\,{\it \sum} \left(  \left( ab+{b}^{2}+{c}^{2}+ac \right) ^{3}
 \left( c+a \right)  \left( a+b \right)  \right) $

<=>(In $\triangle ABC$,subs...)

$a->s-a,b->s-b,c->s-c$
<=>
$$f=216\,{s}^{8}-1296\,r \left( r+2\,R \right) {s}^{6}+1728\,{r}^{2}
 \left( 4\,Rr+2\,{R}^{2}+{r}^{2} \right) {s}^{4}-48\,{r}^{3} \left( 4
\,R+r \right)  \left( 13\,{r}^{2}+158\,Rr+136\,{R}^{2} \right) {s}^{2}
+232\,{r}^{4} \left( 4\,R+r \right) ^{4}\geq 0$$

But 
$$
f={{\it u2}}^{2} \left( 648\,{r}^{2}{s}^{2}+864\,r{s}^{2}R \right) +{
\it u1}\,{\it u2}\, \left( 149232\,{r}^{5}+64704\,R{r}^{4}+56832\,{R}^
{2}{r}^{3}+6912\,{s}^{2}{r}^{3} \right) +{\it u1}\, \left( 130624\,{r}
^{7}+968704\,{R}^{3}{r}^{4}+115008\,{R}^{2}{r}^{5} \right) +{\it u2}\,
 \left( 216\,{s}^{6}+19008\,{s}^{2}{R}^{2}{r}^{2}+350760\,{r}^{6}
 \right) +{\it u3}\, \left( 203568\,R{r}^{5}+3024\,{r}^{2}{s}^{4}
 \right) 
\geq 0$$

as
${\it u1}=R-2\,r,{\it u2}={s}^{2}-16\,Rr+5\,{r}^{2},{\it u3}=4\,{R}^{2
}+4\,Rr+3\,{r}^{2}-{s}^{2}
$
Done!

Here i did not understood how did he sustituted in this portion

> <=>(In $\triangle ABC$,subs...)
>   $a->s-a,b->s-b,c->s-c$\ <=>$$f=216\,{s}^{8}-1296\,r \left( r+2\,R \right) {s}^{6}+1728\,{r}^{2}
>  \left( 4\,Rr+2\,{R}^{2}+{r}^{2} \right) {s}^{4}-48\,{r}^{3} \left( 4
> \,R+r \right)  \left( 13\,{r}^{2}+158\,Rr+136\,{R}^{2} \right) {s}^{2}
> +232\,{r}^{4} \left( 4\,R+r \right) ^{4}\geq 0$$But$$f={{\it u2}}^{2} \left( 648\,{r}^{2}{s}^{2}+864\,r{s}^{2}R \right) +{
> \it u1}\,{\it u2}\, \left( 149232\,{r}^{5}+64704\,R{r}^{4}+56832\,{R}^
> {2}{r}^{3}+6912\,{s}^{2}{r}^{3} \right) +{\it u1}\, \left( 130624\,{r}
> ^{7}+968704\,{R}^{3}{r}^{4}+115008\,{R}^{2}{r}^{5} \right) +{\it u2}\,
>  \left( 216\,{s}^{6}+19008\,{s}^{2}{R}^{2}{r}^{2}+350760\,{r}^{6}
>  \right) +{\it u3}\, \left( 203568\,R{r}^{5}+3024\,{r}^{2}{s}^{4}\right) \geq 0$$as$${\it u1}=R-2\,r,{\it u2}={s}^{2}-16\,Rr+5\,{r}^{2},{\it u3}=4\,{R}^{2
> }+4\,Rr+3\,{r}^{2}-{s}^{2}$$Done!

Comment: Can you explain, why you are looking for a very ugly solution, when you have a very easy and nice proof?

Comment: I just want to understand the other solution..i did it with an easy solution..but i also want to know other solutions of this question too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z = a + b$, $y = c+a$ and $x = b+c$ (correspondingly, $a = \frac{y+z-x}{2}, b = \frac{z+x-y}{2}$ and $c = \frac{x+y-z}{2}$). Then $x, y, z$ are side lengths of a triangle.

We need to prove that $f(a, b, c) \ge 0$ for $a, b, c\ge 0$.
Equivalently, we turn to prove that $f(x, y, z)\ge 0$ where $x, y, z$ are side lengths of a triangle.

We have the following relation:
\begin{align}
&\left\{\begin{array}{l}
         s = \frac{x+y+z}{2} \\[4pt]
         R = \frac{xyz}{\sqrt{(x+y+z)(x+y-z)(y+z-x)(z+x-y)}} \\[6pt]
         r = \frac{\sqrt{(x+y+z)(x+y-z)(y+z-x)(z+x-y)}}{2(x+y+z)} 
       \end{array}
\right.\\[10pt]
&\Longleftrightarrow 
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
         x+y+z = 2s, \\
         xy+yz+ zx = s^2 + 4Rr + r^2 \\
         xyz = 4sRr.         
       \end{array}
\right.
\end{align}
There are many relations among $s, R, r$, e.g., $R \ge 2r$ (Euler's inequality).

Then, $f(x, y, z)$ is written in terms of $s, R, r$.
Now we need to prove that $f(s, R, r)\ge 0$.

Comment: So much step jump in his solution. By the way thanks. Now i understood

Comment: @SohamChatterjee You are welcome.